# Store a column as a string in kdb

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a table with numerous columns. I'm trying to take the data from one of the columns and return it as a string.

For instance, if I had:

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I would like to take column B and store 258 as a string. 
How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
q)raze exec string B from ([] A:1 4 7;B:2 5 8;C:3 6 9)
"258"
```

Or are you trying to change the type of the column in the table?

```
q)update string B from ([] A:1 4 7;B:2 5 8;C:3 6 9)
A B    C
--------
1 ,"2" 3
4 ,"5" 6
7 ,"8" 9
```

Answer (score 2):

If all your entries are single digit numbers, all you need to do is

```
.Q.n t.B
```

Taking your data as an example,

```
q)show t:([] A:1 4 7;B:2 5 8;C:3 6 9)
A B C
-----
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
q).Q.n t.B
"258"
```

Note that `.Q.n` is simply a string containing the 10 digits:

```
q).Q.n
"0123456789"
```

If you want to store the string back in the table, just use `update`:

```
q)update .Q.n B from `t
`t
q)t.B
"258"
```